# p-adic Laguerre root-finding algorithm?

Tags: roots, p-adic-number-theory

If it weren't for the square-root in the last step of the Laguerre root-finding algorithm, the algorithm itself could operate over the p-adics (or just about anything that has a useful concept of derivative).

Is there an alternative operation that could be substituted for the square-root, even if that meant slower convergence?

Comment: Is Newton’s method for root finding not useful here? That’s my knee jerk answer here which might be missing something obvious. It only depends on divisibility

Comment: Laguerre converges faster than Newton (in Euclidean spaces). On way of looking at it is that that Laguerre is optimised for polynomials (it doesn't work with arbitrary functions, where Newton's method often can). If we're in a p-adic space, then we're likely to be only working with polynomials, so maybe there's a Laguerre-based method might be more efficient.

Comment: I see. So you want faster than Newton iteration for polynomial root finding specifically (do you have a particular convergence speed in mind)

Comment: Not particularly, but Laguerre is cubic, where Newton is quadratic (if I remember correclty).